# Problema com as actions no reduxsauce

Tags: react-native, redux

Eu estou fazendo uma app simples de cadastro de receitas em react native e estou utilizando o redux com duck pattern e reduxsauce, segue o código:

```js
//DUCK DE RECEITA

import { createActions, createReducer } from 'reduxsauce';

//Criando actions types e creators
export const { Types, Creators } = createActions({
    addReceita: ["receita"],
    removeReceita: ["id"]
});

//criando Reducers Handlers
const INITIAL_STATE = [];

const add = (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => [
    ...state,
    {id: Math.random(), receita: action.receita}
];

const remove = (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => 
                state.filter(todo => todo.id != action.id);

//Crinado Reducer
export default createReducer(INITIAL_STATE, {
    [Types.ADD_RECEITA]: add,
    [Types.REMOVE_RECEITA]: remove
});
```

O problema é que por algum motivo a função `createActions` do `reduxsauce` não está criando os `Creators`. A const `Creators` está sendo retornada como um objeto vazio, porém a const `Types` está sendo retornada corretamente.  E eu não encontrei nada sobre esse problema. Alguém sabe o que pode estar causando isso?